# Best Text Document Classification Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, text-mining, document-classification

I would like to know the best available algorithms for text Classification. I want to classify the document based on Sports, Bank, technology etc.Please suggest good algorithms to get highest accuracy.

Comment: machine learning is not so easy. I suggest you start with MOOC by Andrew Ng to get a general idea what is it all about

Answer (score 1):

There is no best algorithm. See "4th Law of Data Mining – “NFL-DM” http://khabaza.codimension.net/index_files/9laws.htm

You do want an algorithm that can handle many columns. More columns than rows if need be. This rules out matrix-based algorithms.

Naive Bayes and SVM are popular choices for text classification.

Comment: I tried with Naive Bayes but couldn't get good accuracy. How can i increase the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

The good accuracy is not only based on the machine-learning algorithm. Is is also based on the feature selection. 
Try to define task specific features or analyze your feature space.